# Login com Javascript e PHP - Dando Reload sozinho

Tags: php, javascript, login

tenho um sistema de login PHP com JS que esta me dando um probleminha... Quando eu clico em login, errando a senha, não digitando nada ou digitando, ele me retorna a uma janela avisando se errei a senha, se deixei campo em branco ous e loguei, só que a mensagem aparece e some em menos de 1 segundo, e já redireciona novamente para a index.php

Js

```
var aviso = {
    inicia: function(titulo, conteudo){
        $('body').css({'margin':'0px', 'padding':'0px'}).prepend('<div id="sombra"></div><div id="alerta"><div id="a_dentro"><div id="topo_alerta">'+titulo+'<div id="close_alerta"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>'+conteudo+'</div></div>');
        $('#close_alerta').click(function(){
             $('#alerta').fadeOut(200);
             $('#sombra').fadeOut(200);
        });
    }
}
function logar(e){
var usuarioo = $('#usuario').val();
var senhaa = $('#senha').val();
if(usuarioo == '' || senhaa == ''){
aviso.inicia('Esqueceu algo!', 'Digite um usu&aacute;rio e uma senha!');
}else{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {'usuario':usuarioo, 'senha':senhaa},
url: "library/logar.php",
success: function(html) {
aviso.inicia('Aviso', html);
}
}); 
}
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include "configuracoes/config.php";

$usuarioo = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhaa = $_POST['senha'];

$sql_usuario = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuarioo' AND senha='$senhaa' AND status='Ativo'");
$verifica_numero = mysql_num_rows($sql_usuario);
$exibe_usuario = mysql_fetch_array($sql_usuario);

if($verifica_numero > 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $exibe_usuario['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $exibe_usuario['nome'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $exibe_usuario['id'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $exibe_usuario['senha'];

    $data = date("d/m/Y");
    $hora = date("G:i:s");
    echo'Logado com sucesso!';
    echo'<script>location.reload();</script>';

    $trocar_ip = mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET ip_atual='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE usuario='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'");

    $insere_log = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs_acessos (usuario, texto, ip) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."', '<b>                           ".$_SESSION['nome']."</b> logou na Intranet em <b>".$data."</b> às <b>".$hora."</b>', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')");

}else{
    echo'Usu&aacute;rio ou senha incorreta!';
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<?php if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){ ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="logar" />
            <label id="titulo_login">Login:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input_login" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="usuário">
            <label id="titulo_login" style="margin-left:15px;">Senha:</label>
            <input type="password" class="input_login" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="senha">
            <input type="submit" id="log-in" class="logar" href='javascript:;' onclick='logar();' value="Login">
        </form>
        <div id="txt_login">
            Se você ainda não possui conta na Intranet,vá na Sec. Informática para realizar seu cadastro!
        </div>
        <?php }else{?>
        Logado! <div style="float:left;" onClick="sair();">Sair</div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.

Adiciona a seguinte linha em baixo de function logar(e){, ficando assim:

```js
...
function logar(e){
  e.preventDefault();
...
```

e.preventDefault() informa ao navegador para não seguir com a requisição http, assim ele executa seu código js e permanece na mesma página.

Comment: Brother, deu não, ele só da um reload na página e não da nenhuma resposta, nem loga, nem de erro de senha..